Cant restore a Azure database using sqlpackage?
I am trying to restore my azure database . it is a bacpac file . The bacpac file is about 30Gig  I am using the following command.
   sqlpackage.exe" /a:import /tcs:"Data Source=<my-server>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=NewRestoreDB;User Id=<userid>;Password=<pwd>" /sf:"C:\temp\Test.bacpac"

  /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P15

It gives error:
Transaction (Process ID ) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
I set the DatabaseEdition=Premium and DatabaseServiceObjective=P15
I tried to run the command in command prompt as administrator.
The actual Database on Azure is only Standard and S9
How can i restore the db ?
